# Function to capitalize first and last letter of each word not working

Tags: javascript

I created a function that given any string will return the string with the first and last letter of each word capitalized. So far it works in some words, not on others, can someone help me figure out why?

```
function Capitalize(str) {
  var spl = str.split(" "); 
  var words = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < spl.length; i++) {
    //For every word
    for (let j = 0; j < spl[i].length; j++) {
      //For every letter in each word
      var word = spl[i];
      var size = spl[i].length;
      var firstLetterCapital = word.replace(word[0], word[0].toUpperCase()); //Creates new array
      var LastLetterCapital = firstLetterCapital.replace(
        word[size - 1],
        word[size - 1].toUpperCase()
      );
    }
    words.push(LastLetterCapital);
  }
  console.log(words.join(" "));
}

Capitalize("hello there");
```

It works when I type : `Capitalize("my name is john smith")`, but not with `Capitalize("hello there")`

I know it's a complete mess and probably a very bad way to do it, but I started programming a month ago so give me a break :)

Comment: Can you show your function?

Comment: `var LastLetterCapital = firstLetterCapital.replace(
        word[size - 1],
        word[size - 1].toUpperCase()
      );` makes no sense, what happens if the letter is somewhere else in the word?

Comment: @epascarello Where else would the last letter in the word be? Caesar cipher, by George!

Comment: What is the use of the `j` loop to iterate over characters when you need to work only on words?

Comment: Ask yourself why you have an inner loop. You never actually *use* `j`.

Comment: lol its true, i never actually got to use the inner loop.

Comment: split by ' ' convert the separate words to char arrays, change first and last to upper in the char array, convert back to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@symlink has already explained why it is "HellO ThEre" instead of "Hello TherE". He also has given a solution to explicitly target first and last character of the string. I have accomplished not much different than already posted by members, except for .. "may be" a little more explanation.

You can break the entire problem in these four steps.

1. Get all the words into an array.
2. Create a function, that takes each word and targets first and last character, changes it and returns the changed word.
3. Apply a mapping step using the function created above (in step 2) to the entire array of words (obtained in step 1).
4. Join the transformed array, obtained in step 3, using a blank space as a separator.

I have written two functions that accomplish this task. I am sorry for long name of functions. It helps me keep track of things in a complex program (especially when I am in a hurry!).

***Step 2 function***

```js
function Capitalize_FirstAndLast_One_Word(word){
// Split the string in array for easy access/manipulation by indexing
    Split_String = word.split("")
// Target the first word
    Split_String[0] = Split_String[0].toUpperCase();
// Target the last word
    Split_String[Split_String.length - 1] = Split_String[Split_String.length - 1].toUpperCase();
// Join the array into a single word
    Joined_Back = Split_String.join("")
    return Joined_Back;
}
```

***Step 1, 3 and 4 function***

```js
function Capitalize_Entire_String(str){
 Regular_Exp = new RegExp(/\w+/g);  

//Below is step 1
 MatchedArray = str.match(Regular_Exp);

//Below is step 3
 ConvertedArray = MatchedArray.map(Capitalize_FirstAndLast_One_Word);

// Below is step 4
 ReturnedString = ConvertedArray.join(" ");
 console.log(ReturnedString);
 return ReturnedString;
}
```

Now you have everything. You can use the function like below.

```js
Capitalize_Entire_String("hello there");
Capitalize_Entire_String("hello there this is a test");
```

Hope this helps. I am sorry if this turned out to be a redundant answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Reason your code don't work is the use of `replace()`. `replace()` will always replace the first character found.

There is absolutely no reason to run a nested loop. You can achieve this using a single loop.

```js
function cap(str){
  let spl = str.split(' ');
  for(let i = 0; i < spl.length; i++){
    let temp = spl[i];
    temp = temp[0].toUpperCase() + temp.slice(1)
    temp = temp.slice(0,-1) + temp[temp.length - 1].toUpperCase();
    spl[i] = temp;
  }
  return spl.join(' ');
}

console.log(cap("a quick brown fox"))
```

An easier way is to use `map()` and template strings.

```js
const cap = str => str
                     .split(' ')
                     .map(x => (
                         x.length === 1 ? 
                             x.toUpperCase() : 
                            `${x[0].toUpperCase()}${x.slice(1,-1)}${x[x.length -1].toUpperCase()}`)
                     )  
                     .join(' ')

console.log(cap("a quick brown fox"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Congrats on starting out programming...

You can use this to achieve what you want to do

```
function capitalizeFirstAndLastLetters (str) {
    const words = str.split(" "); // Split the string into words
    const modified = [];

    for (const word of words) {
        if (word.length <= 2) {
            modified.push(word.toUpperCase()); // If the word less than 3 characters, the whole word is capitalized
            continue;
        }

        var firstCapital = word[0].toUpperCase(); // word[0] gets the first index of the string (I.e. the first letter of the word)
        var lastCapital = word.slice(-1).toUpperCase(); // The slice function slices a portion of the word. slice(-1) gets the last letter
        var middlePart = word.slice(1, -1); // slice(1, -1) means start slicing from the second index (I.e. 1) and ignore the last index

        modified.push(firstCapital + middlePart + lastCapital);
    }

    return modified.join(" "); // Join each element in the modified array with a space to get the final string with each words first and last letters capitalized
}

capitalizeFirstAndLastLetters("hello there I am a boy"); // "HellO TherE I AM A BoY"
```

Comment: This capitalizes the first and last letter of the entire string, not each word, though.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the function, you could [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) the string into an array, [map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) each word to the desired format, and [join](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) it together into a string again.

```js
function Capitalize(str){
 return str.split(" ").map((word) => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + 
  (word.length > 2 ? word.substring(1, word.length - 1) : "") + 
  (word.length > 1 ? word.charAt(word.length - 1).toUpperCase() : "")).join(" ");
}

console.log(Capitalize("i want to capitalize first and last letters"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for hello world because I guess you want the outcome to be HellO TherE right?:

```
  function capitalize(str) {
  var spl = str.split(" "); 
  var words = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < spl.length; i++) {
    //For every word

    let changedWord = "";
    for (let j = 0; j < spl[i].length; j++) {
      //For every letter in each word
      if(j == 0 || j == spl[i].length - 1) {
        changedWord += spl[i][j].toUpperCase();
      } else {
        changedWord += spl[i][j].toLowerCase();
      }

    }
    words.push(changedWord);
    console.log(words);
  }
  console.log(words.join(" "));
}

capitalize("hello there");
```

**ALSO: Make your functions name start with lowercase letter. Thats just how it is. Starting with uppercase letters usually are Classes. Just a quick tip**

Comment: I didn't know if I was supposed to start with lowercase or uppercase letter, just used the one that looked better :) Thanks!

Comment: One may argue that the function `Capitalize` is the only exception to the above rule ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```js
function Capitalize(str) {
  return str.replace(/(\b\w|\w\b)/g, l => l.toUpperCase())
}

console.log(Capitalize('i want to be capitalized in a rather strange way'))
```

#### Explanation:

In the [regular expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info) `/(\b\w|\w\b)/g`, `\b` means "word boundary" and `\w` means "word character", so `(\b\w|\w\b)` matches a word boundary followed by a word character OR a word character followed by a word boundary (i.e. the first and last character of words).

The matches of this expression are then passed to the inline function `l => l.toUpperCase()` (which itself is the [second argument to `replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)) that capitalizes the passed letter.

Comment: This works but I think as he said he is new to programming (1 month ago) you might need to explain this a bit more for him to understand what is going on here as he probably doesn't know what this does

Comment: True, added some explanation.

Comment: Yeah, indeed I had absolutely no idea what you had done there :), thanks for the reply and help

Answer (score 0):

This expression:

```
var LastLetterCapital = firstLetterCapital.replace(
    word[size - 1],
    word[size - 1].toUpperCase()
  );
```

Is replacing the *first* occurrence of the character "e" in "There" with an uppercase "E".

#### Explanation

The `replace()` function first translates the first param: `word[size - 1]` to the literal character "e", then replaces the first occurrence of that character with the uppercase "E", resulting in the string "ThEre".

#### Solution

Use a regular expression as your first parameter instead, to ensure that the *last* character is targeted, regardless of whether or not that same character shows up anywhere else in the word:

```
  var LastLetterCapital = firstLetterCapital.replace(/.$/, word[size - 1].toUpperCase());
```

```js
function Capitalize(str) {
  var spl = str.split(" "); 
  var words = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < spl.length; i++) {
    //For every word
    var word = spl[i];
    var size = spl[i].length;
    for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      //For every letter in each word      
      var firstLetterCapital = word.replace(word[0], word[0].toUpperCase()); //Creates new array
      var LastLetterCapital = firstLetterCapital.replace(/.$/, word[size - 1].toUpperCase());
    }
    words.push(LastLetterCapital);
  }
  console.log(words.join(" "));
}

Capitalize("hello there");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this does what you want, don't want to change much from your code:

```js
function Capitalize(str) {
  var spl = str.split(" "); 
  var words = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < spl.length; i++) {
    
    var word = spl[i];
    
    var firstCapital = word[0].toUpperCase(); // get first character after capitalizing
    var lastCapital = word.slice(-1).toUpperCase(); // get last character after capitalizing
    var midOriginal = word.slice(1, -1);
    
    words.push(firstCapital + midOriginal + lastCapital) // concat 3 parts
    
  }
  console.log(words.join(" "));
}

Capitalize("hello there");
```

Answer (score 0):

the string type is immutable, so why don't you try to convert the string to an array like y = word.split('') and do y[0] = word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() and then convert back to string with y.join('')